# Find an element within the current set with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am making a jQuery plugin, how do I find a `.selected` element within the current set?

```
$('a').selected(); // initial set `a`

$.fn.selected = function() {

 return $('.selected', this); 
 // produces `a .selected` but I want to find `a.selected`

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
return this.filter('.selected');
```

... as `this` within jQuery prototype extension function (`$.fn.selected`, in your case) refers to jQuery object itself.